# Hide Facebook Application development

Tags: facebook

I want to develop a facebook app. The only thing I want to know is will this (the fact that I am developing an app) be shared to my friends? If yes how can I disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your question - what exactly do you think would be shared with your friends?

Unless you post something from your app there's no way for a third party to even know that it exists, let alone who runs it. Even the app's info page won't show the developer info unless they choose to enable that.

There's also test accounts you can create via the app edit interface or API ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ ) to test the app without using your own

{edit} Also, as Derek says, you can use sandbox mode while testing so the app and its content aren't visible to anyone except the admins, developers and test users{/edit}

Comment: great..thats sufficient..i got it..thank u Igy..thank u Derek

Answer (score 1):

You can enabled "Sandbox mode" which should disable all notifications and public access to your app.